# Postgres - grant permission to an existing user in a role group

Tags: postgresql, user-roles

I am trying to grant permissions to a user within a role group, where are the steps that I did:

1. create the user: myuser
2. create the role group: read_only
3. `grant read_only to myuser`
4. `grant select on all tables in schema public to read_only`
5. `alter default priviliges in schema public grant select on tables to read_only`

after all the steps above, when I use `myuser` to query the tables, I got 'permission denied'. Anything I missed here?

Comment: You've only altered the *default privileges* for new tables that will be created in that schema, you haven't given any grants to existing tables

Comment: @Bergi yes, actually I had that step in step#4 but still couldn't query the table.

Answer (score 1):

Altering default privileges only affects new tables.  You will want to grant the privileges on all existing tables by issuing the below in order for you to have permissions.

```
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO read_only;
```

Comment: I had this step (#4) prior to 'alter privileges'' statement, but still can't query the table.